# Quickly view summary of pending changes within each file in TFS 2012

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to view a summary screen showing the changes that have been made to each file within the pending changes window in TFS 2012? I know that I can right-click each file and compare with workspace or latest but that can be painful if I have a large check-in to commit and I want to quickly scan through to see which files actually have changes and which have simply been checked out but not edited (for example). Git has a nice feature in Git Extensions and the VS Source Control plugin that shows the deltas for each file when you select it. Is there something similar hidden away in TFS? In the power tools perhaps or via a different plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do a hierarchy compare by right clicking on any file in the "Source Control Explorer" and selecting compare.  You can see each file that has real changes and double click to get details.  Also, if you need a better way to find your pending changes, there is a "pending changes" filter on the Visual Studio 2012 Solution explorer.  It's better than using the "Team Explorer" window for that purpose in my opinion.

[Comparing Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385986.aspx)

[showing-files-with-pending-changes-or-files-that-are-open-in-visual-studio-2012-solution-explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/08/14/showing-files-with-pending-changes-or-files-that-are-open-in-visual-studio-2012-solution-explorer.aspx)

Comment: +1 for the pending changes filter - I hadn't spotted that before. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you'll ever get anything as nice as Git's pending changes window because TFS has to go back to the server to fetch the latest version of each file in order to do the compare. It would effectively have to cache every file you'd changed to provide an interface where you could see changes across the entire commit. Git is simply doing a comparison against files in your local repository. The folder compare is a nice feature though. Comparing files from there is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and my colleague found that the VS2015 TFS web portal is the way to go!  It provides two great features:

1. pending changes view similar to GIT Extensions
2. auto-complete people's names when searching for shelfsets

**How do I find TFS online web portal?**

The web portal address syntax for VS2015 is:
http://*ServerName*:8080/tfs/*CollectionName*/*ProjectName*

Further info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee523998.aspx

**How do I get a GIT-Extensions-like diff view of TFS pending changes?**

To view your own local changes, you'll first need to save them as a shelfset.  Or if you're reviewing someone else's shelfset, then just go to the TFS web portal address.

Navigate to the web portal address (you may need to log into Office365) then click the "CODE" menu link top-left, then click the tab "Shelvesets" as shown in this screenshot:

[image: View TFS shelfset changes online to get GIT-Extsnions-like comparison window]

From here, you can search for shelfsets and it even auto-completes people's names for you!  Once you've found the shelfset you want to review, click it's hyperlinked name and - although not as fast as GIT - single-clicking a file name will display a diff of its changes.  Hey presto!

Here's a screenshot showing the online diff, accessed by a single-click on the filename in the shelfset list of changed files (blocked out namespaces for privacy):

[image: Example of TFS online diff, similar to GIT Extensions]

You can also do something similar with code already checked in by viewing the "Changesets" tab.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing available at the moment for this (unless there's a little-known plugin I've not heard of). Team Explorer is supposed to be easy to extend, so maybe someone will develop one. But it's not in VS2012 or the Team Foundation Power Toys.

Comment: I suspected as much. Thanks @DaveShaw. I'll leave this question open in case someone does indeed develop one